# How to go about storing users data in Json

Tags: python, json, database

I have been messing with Json a bit today and doing some trial and error but I couldn't seem to make this work:

```
def checkForNewBooty(chan):
    j = urllib2.urlopen('http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/' + chan + '/chatters')
    j_obj = json.load(j)
    viewers = j_obj['chatters']['viewers']
    moderators = j_obj['chatters']['moderators']
    for x in viewers and moderators:
        print(json.dumps('users' = {'johhny' = {'Points' = 0, 'Time Joined' = 9938}}))
```

Json example of what I'm trying to do:

```
{
  users = {
    "johhnyknoxville" 
  }
}
```

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Actually I don't understand what are you doing...Which part doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python dictionaries (which are serialized using JSON) use `:` and not `=`.

Try:

```
json.dumps({'users': {'johhny': {'Points': 0, 'Time Joined': 9938}}})
```